# Conditional compile for an Android Cordova app

Tags: java, android, cordova, conditional-compilation

I have a Cordova/Android hybrid app that uses one custom - inhouse - plugin.  Amongst other things the plugin fetches and displays AdMob ads.  In my debug builds as I test things out I am using Google's test ads using

```
String deviceID = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();   
builder.addTestDevice(deviceID);
```

No issues thus far - as I am testing the app I see safe test ads as expected.  However, I want to guard against the day when I create a release build and ship it off to Play Store with that test ad code.  I was wondering ... is there a way to put that code in a conditional compile block that only forks in when it detects that the build in question is a Cordova debug build - `cordova build android --debug`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a try [this plugin](https://github.com/mattlewis92/cordova-plugin-is-debug)

> cordova-plugin-is-debug A cordova plugin to detect if the app is
>   running in debug mode or not. Debug mode is when the app is built and
>   installed locally via xcode / eclipse / the cordova cli etc, compared
>   to release mode when the app was downloaded from the app / play store
>   via an end user. Common use cases include:
>
> using a different API endpoint for development using a different push
>   notification certificate for development and production

Then I guess your plugin would have to use this plugin at runtime

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I don't quite follow the "a plugin for everything" philosophy of development.  However, I was able to easily integrate the rather very limited functionality delivered by that plugin into my own custom plugin.